# List Comprehension if-else ladder

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given a sentence, return the sentence will call its letter transposed by 1 in the alphabet, but only if the letter is a-y.

```
# input
'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
# output
'uif rvjdl cspxo gpy kvnqt pwfs uif mbzy eph'
```

I tried this:

```
a = [chr(ord(i) + 1) if ord(i) != ord(' ') else i if i =='y' else i for i in input() if ord(i) < ord('z')]
print(''.join(a))
```

output I'm getting (`y` is missing here in lazy word i.e. `mbzy`):

```
uif rvjdl cspxo gpy kvnqt pwfs uif mbz eph
```

Comment: Do you have to do this using a list comprehension? It looks extremely convoluted. A simple for loop will do the job and would be way easier to understand

Comment: What is the point of the trailing ``i if i =='y' else i``? It seems to always evaluate to ``i``.

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect the output ``mbzy``? Shifting all letters by one should transform ``lazy`` to ``mbzz`` or ``mbaz``, depending on how ``z`` is shifted. Why would ``y`` be preserved?

Comment: On another note: [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says "readability counts". I'm not sure if fitting the whole operation on a single line is a part of your assignment, but it's far from readable. I bet if you'd read that code after a few weeks you'll be confused what is it about. Don't be afraid to break it down into more simple operations which are easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
print(''.join([c if c == ' ' or ord(c) >= ord('y') else chr(ord(c) + 1) for c in a]))
```

output

```
uif rvjdl cspxo gpy kvnqt pwfs uif mbzy eph
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the trick. I changed up some of your conditions, and removed the condition at the end (`ord(i) < ord('z')`) because it was preventing the 'z' character from being processed.

Also, comparison operators work on characters and integers, so you don't always need to use 'ord()' in your conditions.

```
a = [chr(ord(i) + 1) if i != ' ' and i < 'y' else i for i in input()]

print(''.join(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the instruction, this code worked for me:

```
what_to_return = ""
for char in input():
    what_to_return += char if char == 'y' or char == 'z' else chr(ord(char) + 1) if 'a' <= char < 'z' else " "
```

output:

```
uif rvjdl cspxo gpy kvnqt pwfs uif mbzy eph
```